# Heroku Application Error: can't migrate the database properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, carrierwave, heroku-postgres, cloudinary

After installing CarrierWave and Cloudinary, my Heroku app won't start.  Based  on the logs, Heroku doesn't recognize one of the CarrierWave methods even though it works in development. ("Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Image::ImageFileUploader")

I've tried heroku run rake db:migrate.  I've tried heroku restart. I've tried creating a new app from the same code. What am I doing wrong?

The logs from Heroku:

```html
$ heroku logs
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843432+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843431+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843433+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843436+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843439+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843442+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843443+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843451+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843448+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843454+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843455+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843461+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843464+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843465+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843468+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843469+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843472+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843476+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843480+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843486+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843483+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `new'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843489+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843492+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843499+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:107:in `app'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:113:in `load_and_bind'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:512:in `run'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843509+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843503+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:301:in `run'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-06-01T00:48:53.843515+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-06-01T00:48:54.702444+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-01T00:48:54.731224+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-06-01T00:48:57.895443+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jg2758@gmail.com
2015-06-01T00:49:01.593848+00:00 heroku[run.1852]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-06-01T00:49:01.550327+00:00 heroku[run.1852]: Awaiting client
2015-06-01T00:49:01.828367+00:00 heroku[run.1852]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-01T00:49:06.598219+00:00 heroku[run.1852]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-01T00:49:06.584931+00:00 heroku[run.1852]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-01T00:49:14.826659+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by jg2758@gmail.com
2015-06-01T00:49:19.919812+00:00 heroku[run.1011]: Awaiting client
2015-06-01T00:49:20.109250+00:00 heroku[run.1011]: State changed from starting to up
2015-06-01T00:49:20.176967+00:00 heroku[run.1011]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2015-06-01T00:49:29.612953+00:00 heroku[run.1011]: State changed from up to complete
2015-06-01T00:49:29.607995+00:00 heroku[run.1011]: Process exited with status 0
2015-06-01T00:50:01.774595+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pure-hamlet-4826.herokuapp.com request_id=59f7b06f-a3da-47cd-8d5e-a2ae808a157b fwd="96.49.47.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T00:50:02.100139+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pure-hamlet-4826.herokuapp.com request_id=fcb09e9e-d0a3-4e44-a5fa-4880e4df6c3a fwd="96.49.47.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T00:51:27.697318+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2015-06-01T00:51:32.035368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2015-06-01T00:51:34.635649+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
2015-06-01T00:51:34.635676+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 2.11.1 (ruby 2.0.0-p645), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
2015-06-01T00:51:34.635678+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2015-06-01T00:51:34.635679+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
2015-06-01T00:51:34.635682+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
2015-06-01T00:51:34.635681+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
2015-06-01T00:51:37.489392+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] ! Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Image::ImageFileUploader
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490340+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/models/image.rb:2:in `<class:Image>': uninitialized constant Image::ImageFileUploader (NameError)
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490345+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/app/models/image.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490349+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490350+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490355+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490356+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490360+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490363+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490367+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490371+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490374+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490377+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490380+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490386+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490389+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490391+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490394+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490398+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490402+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490409+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490406+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490413+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `require'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490416+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490420+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490424+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490425+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `new'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490428+00:00 app[web.1]:    from config.ru:in `<main>'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490431+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490438+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:107:in `app'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490443+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/runner.rb:113:in `load_and_bind'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cluster.rb:301:in `run'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490449+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:512:in `run'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490452+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490455+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
2015-06-01T00:51:37.490459+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
2015-06-01T00:51:38.376970+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2015-06-01T00:51:39.573008+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pure-hamlet-4826.herokuapp.com request_id=8ecbed15-ccff-49d0-9dc5-9c89acbdd076 fwd="96.49.47.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2015-06-01T00:51:39.426345+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pure-hamlet-4826.herokuapp.com request_id=ca881b6d-2628-422f-8e1e-281501a15cf4 fwd="96.49.47.172" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
WARNING: Toolbelt v3.37.3 update available.
```

Comment: After recreating the app from scratch, I've isolated the problem to ImageFileUploader.  When it's configured without Cloudinary, I have no problems.  As soon as I configure it for Cloudinary, the app breaks. Still investigating why...

Comment: Any specific error messages you see?

Comment: All I got was the Heroku error template (http://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html) and "! Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Image::ImageFileUploader" in my logs.

Comment: Would you like to share it on Github, so I can try and reproduce it?

Comment: You know what, I migrated the database again this morning, and the error message is gone.  Thank you for the offer, though!

Comment: Sure, no problem. Good to hear it's OK now :)